# ChromaDB PeristentClient goes stuck on Azure Machine Learning Studio when creating local folder

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, chromadb

I've installed chromadb on Azure Machine Learning Studio using python 3.10.13 with following `requirements.txt`:

```
pysqlite3-binary
chromadb
```

Then i want to create a Peristant Client on a `mydir` directory that does not exist:

```
import chromadb

cl = chromadb.PersistentClient(path="mydir")
```

if I execute this code, it stucks for 15mins and then return

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/anaconda/envs/LLM4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromadb/__init__.py", line 106, in PersistentClient
    return Client(settings)
  File "/anaconda/envs/LLM4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromadb/__init__.py", line 145, in Client
    system.start()
  File "/anaconda/envs/LLM4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromadb/config.py", line 269, in start
    component.start()
  File "/anaconda/envs/LLM4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromadb/db/impl/sqlite.py", line 93, in start
    self.initialize_migrations()
  File "/anaconda/envs/LLM4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromadb/db/migrations.py", line 128, in initialize_migrations
    self.apply_migrations()
  File "/anaconda/envs/LLM4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromadb/db/migrations.py", line 147, in apply_migrations
    self.setup_migrations()
  File "/anaconda/envs/LLM4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromadb/db/impl/sqlite.py", line 149, in setup_migrations
    with self.tx() as cur:
  File "/anaconda/envs/LLM4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromadb/db/impl/sqlite.py", line 47, in __exit__
    self._conn.commit()
  File "/anaconda/envs/LLM4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromadb/db/impl/sqlite_pool.py", line 31, in commit
    self._conn.commit()
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked
```

Keep in mind that if i run

```
pip list | grep sql
pysqlite3-binary    0.5.1
```

The foder is create and contains:

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 0 Sep 12 13:45 .
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 0 Dec 12  2022 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep 12 13:45 chroma.sqlite3
```

Any ideas?

I expect the same beheivour of Colab: no block or stuck